# Help with solving 5x5 sub-centers inside 11x11x11 Rubik's cube -- errors in guide book

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

[companion question [here]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119262/82754)

I was given an 11x11x11 Rubik's cube as a gift. It came with a guide book that I have been following to solve the cube.

I have solved four of the 9x9 sub-centers of the cube, and arrived at the step to solve the 5x5 sub-sub-centers of the remaining two. There is an error in the guide book notation, where it has duplicate algorithms (circled in red) to swap two different pairs of pieces:

[image: Picture showing duplicate algorithms]

The top right algorithm is correct -- it swaps the rightmost center piece of the 5x5 sub-centers. However, the bottom left algorithm is incorrect; it does the same thing as the aforementioned one. **What is the correct algorithm to do here?**

Comment: This is a nice first question, welcome to the site! Take a look at our [tour] when you have the chance :) Now, putting on my "advice" hat, I'd suggest that you move the second picture and its duplicated algorithms to a second question. That way, someone could answer just the first picture, or just the second picture, but they don't have to cobble together an answer for the whole thing. Plus, then you can accept two separate answers, awarding multiple people the reputation bonus for solving your problem!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've split the question into two, and posted the other one here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119262/82754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had suspected a fix myself as there was an intuitive pattern among the different algorithms, and Reddit user [XenosHg](https://www.reddit.com/user/XenosHg/) suspected [the same](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/comments/103q3vy/comment/j356wlh/). I tested the new algorithm and confirm that the answer is that the bottom left algorithm should be:

`T4R' F' N7R' F T4R F' N7R`