# Help with solving 7x7 sub-centers inside 11x11x11 Rubik's cube -- errors in guide book

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

[companion question [here]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119260/82754)

I was given an 11x11x11 Rubik's cube as a gift. It came with a guide book that I have been following to solve the cube.

After solving four of the 9x9 sub-centers of the cube, and after solving the 5x5 sub-centers of the remaining two faces, the guidebook prompts to solve the 7x7 sub-centers. There is an error in the guide book notation, where it has duplicate algorithms (circled in red) to "swap" two different pairs of pieces:

[image: Picture showing another pair of duplicate algorithms]

I have not tested either of these duplicate algorithms yet, but I am guessing that the center-right circled algorithm is correct, and need a new algorithm for the bottom left one in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got to this today. I am now used to the intuitive pattern, and I have corrected the mistakes in the algorithms:

[image: Corrections]

There is a general intuitive pattern here, and I will copy and paste Reddit user [XenosHg](https://www.reddit.com/user/XenosHg/) 's [explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/comments/103q3vy/comment/j3586i8) to give credit:

> the center commutator works intuitively like this:
>
> 1. put these 2 pieces in the same column
> 2. slice the piece into its correct place
> 3. rotate that side by 90 degrees so the piece is in a different column. (so you can't rotate upper-right diagonal piece into lower-right diagonal piece, the column must be different)
> 4. slice this new column in the same direction.
> 5. turn back. undo first slice, turn, undo second slice, turn back.
>
> So if you slice from up to front, then you rotate front. If you slice
> from front to up, then you rotate up. Easy.
>
> It doesn't actually swap 2 pieces, 2 pieces is impossible, but it
> swaps 3 pieces, and on a mostly solved cube, you will usually hit 2
> same-color squares out of 3.
>
> 2R U' 2L' U 2R' U' 2L U
>
> [view at CubeDB.net](https://cubedb.net/?puzzle=5&alg=2R_U-_2L-_U_2R-_U-_2L_U&type=alg)